# Setting wpf DataGrid Column style programatically - After a 'SetterBaseCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified

Tags: wpf, datagrid, setter

I am changing my DataGrid's column colors programmatically with the following code:

```
this.ImportPreview.Columns[index].CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
this.ImportPreview.Columns[index].CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)));
```

This works one single time for each column. If I try to change it a second time, the Setter Collection is locked.

The following Error appears:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
'After a 'SetterBaseCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.'
```

I tried clearing the setter collection with the same result:

```
this.ImportPreview.Columns[index].CellStyle.Setters.Clear();
```

I found the following Promising question/answer, but the answer is to shorthanded for me. I do not know how to apply this Answer:
[How to add further style setters programmatically? When I try I got an InvalidOperationException exception (SetterBaseCollection is in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165363/how-to-add-further-style-setters-programmatically-when-i-try-i-got-an-invalidop)

additionally there are a lot of similar questions but they are based around setting the style in xaml whereas I am trying to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding setters to an existing `Style`, you should create a new `Style` and set the `CellStyle` property to this one.

You may base the new `Style` on the existing one and then simply add the additional setters. Something like this:

```
DataGridColumn column = this.ImportPreview.Columns[index];
Style newCellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell), column.CellStyle);
newCellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)));
column.CellStyle = newCellStyle;
```

Comment: thank you, this worked great! (I used the first approach of creating a style and applying the setter to the style. Then assigning the style to the column)